# Solr SpellCheck Component custom freq field?

Tags: solr

I'm currently playing around with the Solr SpellCheck component and at the moment I've a core which is my 'dictionary'. In this core there is a huge list of words with a "score".

Example document:

```
    "keyword":"facebook",
    "frequency":89504,
```

A word is only listed once in the core, so when I execute a spellcheck for example **faceboek**

```
spell?omitHeader=true&wt=xml&json.nl=flat&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=faceboek&spellcheck.build=false
```

it returns **facebook** with a freq of 1 because that word is only listed once in my core. However I want that the freq is going to be my field **frequency**.

Return example:

```
<lst>
  <str name="word">facebook</str>
  <int name="freq">1</int>
</lst>
```

So my question is. Is it possible to modify the **freq** field into the frequency field every document has, or is there another solution to this?

Thank you for your time. I'll provide more information if the question is unclear.

Comment: It's important to note that the `freq` field isn't something that is derived from the _document_, but is calculated from the _tokens_ indexed for a specific field. I don't think any of the standard spellcheckerclasses offer this functionality, but [implementing a custom class might be an option](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/suggest/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/spell)? I'm not sure how easy it'll be to read a different field for the document generating the token match, tho.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for your comment, I also thought about implementing a custom class. However as you can imagine that is my last option since it would require much work. Is there perhaps an option to add a field to the spell query? perhaps that it returns the documents solr suggests?

Comment: Have you considered creating a separate core/collection with your suggestions and use that instead? That will allow you to apply a boost to each document (i.e. suggestion) by using `freq`, and use fuzzy search to find suggestions (if they're misspelled). Depending on the use case, the [Suggester](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html) could also be helpful, but a dedicated collection will give you the most flexibility.

Comment: Thank you, again, for your comment @MatsLindh. Currently, I'm testing the Suggester and it seems to be working like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a separate core/collection with your suggestions and use that instead.

That will allow you to apply a boost to each document (i.e. suggestion) by using freq, and use [fuzzy search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-FuzzySearches) (`q=term~`) to find suggestions (if they're misspelled).

Depending on the use case, [the Suggester](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html) can also be useful, but a dedicated collection will give you the most flexibility (i.e. you can score it any way you want).